# EPPLUS issues with Formulas

Tags: c#, epplus, formulas

Trying to write a simple formula using EPPLUS but cannot seem to find a way around it.

The formula is as follows: =C12-(SUM(D12:E12))

I have tried various combination but not too sure which option will allow me to define such a simple formula.

It always complains about "-" cannot be applied to string string etc.

Any ideas how to write such formula

```
worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, CurrColumn + 1].Formula = "SUBTOTAL" + (worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, iStart_column - 1]) - ("SUM(" + worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, iStart_column, this.CurrRow, CurrColumn]);
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3GWZZi3G this is my last attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you are generating the formulas dynamically.  In which case, you are getting an error because you are using a math `-` on strings which, of course, cannot really be done.  I think what you are going for is something like this:

```
worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, CurrColumn + 1].Formula = "=SUBTOTAL("+ worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, iStart_column - 1].Address + "-(SUM(" + worksheet.Cells[this.CurrRow, iStart_column, this.CurrRow, CurrColumn].Address + ")))";
```

Note the use of the `Address` properties which will give the string representation of the `Cell` objects.

Note: Your implementation of `SUBTOTAL` is not really correct and Excel will complain about it when it opens the file.  This is more an excel problem then a EPPlus so you will have to work that out or post more detail.

Comment: Great. Yeah table is dynamic. Thanks. I'm not too sure which option I should use but will try again and report back. Cheer

Comment: this is strange. I have updated my line and could run the application and produce the excel. the command appears OK but getting #VALUE! message instead. However, If I copy and paste formula from the same cell and paste it elsewhere within the spreadsheet i get the right result.   http://pastebin.com/eySwexzS. Any ideas?